# How do I make this picture even across the screen in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a image at the top of a html file fit across the whole screen with no gaps how can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coding site!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <script src="myscripts.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <img src="coding.jpg" style="width:42px;height:42px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "gap" is present because in most major browsers, the default margin on the `body` element is 8px on all sides. To remove it, add the following CSS styling:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coding site!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <script src="myscripts.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" style="width:42px;height:42px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make its width 100% and margin 0px.

Answer (score 1):

To suit the image to the frame set the width to 100%,and set the body padding: 0; and margin: 0; in the internal CSS file.